# Poor CSS Background Animation

Tags: css, animation, webkit, parallax, css-animations

So I've been working on a simple launch page today for an application i'm working on

I wanted to put a moving background (parallax esque) using some css animation as shown here
http://css-tricks.com/parallax-background-css3/

I used the background-position move in a keyframe config through the webkit animate function

here is a sample

```
#BigWrapper{
    -webkit-animation-name: MOVE;
        transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
        -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
        -webkit-animation-duration: 250s;
        -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
        -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    }
     @-webkit-keyframes MOVE {
     from {

     background-position: 5% 5%;

    }
    to {
        background-position: 1300% 600%;
    }
    }
```

This produced fairly poor performance. the background image is a png32 with transparency
compressed to 896kb. I tried initiating hardware acceleration using a blank translate3d statement but no visible change occured.

I also tried changing the background-position to translate3d instead and it moved the whole
div along with the content it contains. i'm not sure how to produce this effect without performance hits.

here is the test site [www.auroragm.sourceforge.net](http://auroragm.sourceforge.net)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out All I had to do was to tell the browser to stop caching each time there was an update, which apparently helps a lot:

```
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Pragma" CONTENT="no-cache">
```

Did the trick :)

Answer (score 2):

While testing with Chrome and Firefox in Windows XP results in well performance, both your Tile.png and BlurBG.png seem to have a fairly large size. As for me, I'd combine the Tile.png with BlurBG.png into one file as the Tile.png doesn't seem to look as a static background behind the moving BlurBG.png.

But if you want to keep it as separate two files, you might want to reduce the file size more. My personal tool of choice is [PNGoo](http://code.google.com/p/pngoo/).

Comment: Thanks! I guess I was expecting buttery smooth performance, but I'll try combining both files and see if it gives any performance boost. I want to tiles to be separate because it loads faster then the BlurBG and you wont see a white page when you load the site while waiting for BlurBG to load. I also use a png compressor which reduced the 5mb BlurBG to 900kb which is pretty good. but i'll check out PNGoo thanks!

Comment: I have not compared the performance, but perhaps you might want to check Lea Verou's CSS3 carbon fibre pattern too >  http://lea.verou.me/css3patterns/#carbon-fibre :) By modifying the number to 35% (instead of 15%), it will look similar to your Tile.png, but only requires 6 lines of code. Though unfortunately it is not supported in older browsers..

Comment: I doubt that would really help. I'm pretty sure the big problem is the moving image and not the Tiles.png which is rendered before the moving background starts moving. I was looking for a more efficient way of animating the moving background

Comment: Oh sorry, you're right, I meant that the CSS3 pattern technique is just for an alternative for reducing the quite large Tile.png's file size.

Comment: I can compress its not really important to help me solve this, but thanks

Answer (score 1):

That site works surprisingly well at my end, using Firefox or Chrome on Linux.

Which browser are you testing on?  Perhaps IE doesn't response well to animating a large background image.

Consider restricting the animation of the background to certain browsers.

Also, consider darkening the background image somewhat - the moving contrasting colors in the background drowns out the centrepiece.

Comment: Thanks for the feed back. I think restricting the OS is what i'll do, apparently IE9 and iOS are the ones having the problem. I'll also darken the background I also thought it was a bit too much. :)